# Como passar o valor de 2 Select Option por JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho essa função:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#auto').change(function () {
       $('#funcao').load('listaQuestaoAutomatica.php?auto=' + $('#auto').val());
     }).change();
   });
</script>
```

Ela passa o valor do `Select Option` ao selecionar para outro arquivo por parâmetro, nessa linha: `$('#funcao').load('listaQuestaoAutomatica.php?auto=' + $('#auto').val());`

Como faço para passar também nessa função o valor de um 2º Select Option ao escolher que esteja no mesmo arquivo?

1º `select option`:

```
<select name="auto" id="auto">
  <option value="">S/N</option>
  <option value="S">Sim</option>
  <option value="N">Não</option>
</select>
```

2º `select option`:

```
<select name="conta" id="conta">
  <option value="">Selecione</option>
  <option value="+">Somar</option>
  <option value="*">Multiplica</option>
</select>
```

O que desejo é o seguinte, seleciono o 1º `select option`, e só quando selecionar o 2º `select option` ele envie por parâmetro para o link informado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode declarar duas variáveis, uma variável  contendo o valor de `auto` e outra variável contendo o valor de `conta`, com essas duas variáveis é só incluir como parâmetro do seu URL.

> Usei o template string para concatenar os dados.

```
const auto = $('#auto').val();
const conta= $('#conta').val();

$('#funcao').load(`listaQuestaoAutomatica.php?auto=${auto}&conta=${conta}`);
```

### Referências:

- [Template String](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)
- [Load - Jquery](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

#### Exemplo de uso conforme a descrição da pergunta

```
// Executa ao selecionar o segundo select id=conta
$('#conta').change(function () {
    const auto = $('#auto').val();
    const conta= $('#conta').val();

    $('#funcao').load(`listaQuestaoAutomatica.php?auto=${auto}&conta=${conta}`);
});
```

Comment: Perfeito @henriquuepedro, era isso mesmo que estava procurando, vlw.